# How to find which #include contains a function?

Tags: c++

I'm new to looking at big codebases. I can find where a function in a file is declared or implemented, but I'm having trouble figuring out which #include it is. In python it was clear, but in C++ it could be any of the header or #include files. Does anyone know the best way to look for this function?

Comment: Use an IDE or LSP-aware text editor. Both have "Go to definition" functionality.

Comment: That's where a good IDE will come in handy, they often have a "go to declaration" and "definition to definition" functionality for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @arrowd I can find exactly where a function is declared, but this file is not explicitly declared in my current file. So I need to find a way to trace all the way up through the #includes until I can find the definition

Comment: Assuming you are using GCC, you can use `g++ -E foo.cpp | vi -` to see the post-processed file.

Comment: @StarckOverflar well, https://en.cppreference.com is a helpful resource, keeping up with current standards.

Comment: I usually start with the documentation. <g>